# Adding formulas in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I need to replicate formulas from an Excel spreadsheet to a jqgrid grid. Similar to that

[image]

Is jqgrid able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using [JExcel.js](https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v4/)